# VBA cannot dim a UInteger

Tags: vba, integer, unsigned

I try to dim an unsigned integer using the line:

```
dim curStart as UInteger
```

and on running, I receive the error:

Compile Error
"User-defined type not defined"

Is there a reference library that is required in VBA to allow unsigned integers?

I'm using Visual Basic for Applications 7.1.1068

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re out of luck - VBA does not support unsigned types.

Use a Long instead, which is a superset of a 16 bit unsigned type.

Comment: Thanks, I'm confused though because the following documentation mentions UIntegers being available. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/uinteger-data-type

Are Visual Basic and Visual Basic for Applications not the same?

Comment: VB.NET is totally different platform from VBA (despite the similar syntax)